# why use a css document instead of a style tag?

Tags: html

This seems like kind of a basic question. What are the reasons one would choose to use a css document instead of altering the style with the style tags in the html document? Is it not possible, for instance, to alter IDs and classes from within the html style tags? Thanks- this is my first stackoverflow question!

Comment: I think you should be more specific in what you are asking? Show some examples of what you are trying to do figure out?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder, Is is a general question. No code involved.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question.

Comment: @macsplean, This is a very good first question.

Comment: @AnaMaria While this is not bad question it's way too broad. Good answer will take a long time to be created and it will more likely be an article, otherwise answers won't be complete and, probably, they will mislead future readers.

Comment: @PLB, I agree. Its more of a discussion. I was just thinking of it in a newbie sort of sense. I mean it a good question for a first timer on SO

Comment: Please do not ask a question to speculate about reasons. Ask concrete question you face yourself. What is your reason? Why do you ask this yourself?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing technically wrong with using the `style` tag, but most pages have a seperate style sheet file.

**Here are some reasons to use a seperate style sheet file:**

1. The page may load faster due to asynchronous loading by the browser.
2. Seperates your HTML markup from your CSS styles.
3. Caching.
4. Easier to maintain because all the CSS is in one place.

You may also want to look into [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There are several benefits

1. Reusability. An external site sheet can be used by multiple documents, so you don't have to write a new style sheet for each.
2. Coherence.  With external style sheets you can be sure that the documents have at least the same basic styles and are visually consistent. Embedded style sheets tend to drift away from the standard.
3. Performance.  An external style sheet can be cached by the browser, which means it doesn't have to be transferred every time the client requests a document. An embedded style sheet has to be transferred every time the browser requests a document.
4. Maintainability. If you have a set of documents that have the same visual appearance, and a change has to be made (changes to the corporate identity for example), if the style sheet is external you have to change it in only one place. Using embedded styles you would have to make the same change in each document.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

In my own words, using CSS makes thing a lot simpler as adding styles for each tag in HTML is basically just not practical. Hence defining how a particular element will look on the page just once and then reusing the same style multiple times saves a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

CSS files is cacheable by the browser, the style tag in an HTML document just adds an extra file size overhead that needs to be downloaded everytime.